# is this diagram is daily_seasonality and yearly_seasonality?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, timeserieschart, facebook-prophet

I am trying to create a time series model, I just need a help for specifying the type of this blue line in the graph sown below.
I am using `fbprophet`, the code is:

```
model = Prophet(interval_width=0.97,daily_seasonality=True,yearly_seasonality=True)
```

Is this daily_seasonality and yearly_seasonality?

The graph is:

[image: this is the graph]

Answer (score 0):

Your plot is quite unclear and we might need more info about the data, from what I see I'd guess it is covid related (pure guess). Seasonality is cumulative so `daily_seasonality=True, yearly_seasonality=True` leads up to sum of yearly and daily seasonality. However, yearly seasonality will not play a role since you have data from just a year. So in this case, only daily information have value. You might be interested in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-start-of-time-series-forecasting-with-a-practical-example-using-fb-prophet-31c4447a2274), where authors take in consideration even data from holiday events.